# Vertical line of white pixels between launcher and maximized application (Firefox)

Tags: unity, firefox, gui

[image]

Is this a bug or is it expected?

How can it be solved if it's not expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marco Trevisan has [confirmed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1373118/comments/6) this to be a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's something to do with the Unity sidebar, since Chrome and the file manager do this too.

Try using other themes to see if this persists.

[image: Chrome]

[image: Nautilus]

Comment: I can only notice it on light wallpapers by the way. Still waiting for confirmation from other users that this isn't a bug for now though.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Compiz. There seem to be dozens of bug reports if you google it and it's been present for years, probably as a regression. It's terrible.

Comment: Damn... Hopefully such annoyances will be history when Mir comes around.